# Produce a bijection from some segment in $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}^+$

Tags: abstract-algebra

My abstract algebra text is asking me the following:

> Let $A = \{ q \in \mathbb{Q} : a < q < b\}$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$
>
> Prove $|A| = |\mathbb{Q}^+|$

I realize I have two options:

1. Explicitly produce a bijection between the two sets
2. Show that one exists but don't produce one explicitly

Option 1 is actually pretty simple. Let $$g:A\to\mathbb{Q^+}:q\to\frac{1}{q-a}-\frac{1}{b-a}$$

However I felt like I was doing engineering not pure math when I tried to figure that one out. Is there a less hacky and more logic-bound way to do this?

Comment: Are $a,b$ rationnal too ?

Comment: Good point. I'll add that in

Comment: I would argue that the first one is always better, because it is *constructive*. It does not only show that there exists a bijection, but also what it is. Knowing the concrete bijection may sometimes be helpful for someone who wants to makes use of that bijection.

Comment: Now I have a question about the process of developing answer (1) – I experimented with the function a bit using a graphical calculator because I felt like it was the right tool for the job. Would you consider my use of that tool philosophically cheating or merely taking advantage of tools that help you think and iterate ideas faster.

Comment: I think any way of coming up with a legitimate answer is fine. However, once you have come up with an answer, you need to *prove* that this answer is actually correct. In the proof, you cannot cheat.

Comment: I'm not sure why it is "hacky".  I'd say I need a way so that as $x\rightarrow b$ then $f(x)\rightarrow \infty$ which requires finding an $\espilon; M$ conversion.  Then standard is for $x = b-h; f(x) = 1/h$ or so.  So $f(x) = 1/(b-x)$.  Bu that's only one sid $f(a+h) = 1/(b-a-h)$ which doesn't tend to zero.  But a simple shift $f(x) = 1/(b-x) - 1/(b-a)$ will do it.

Answer (score 2):

The restriction to rational numbers is almost a red herring.

The function $x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{x-b} - \dfrac{1}{a-b}$ is a bijection $(a,b) \to (0,+\infty)$.

When $a,b \in \mathbb Q$, this function maps rationals to rationals and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to show it: clearly you have an injection $(a,b)\cap {\bf Q} \to {\bf Q}$, and if $N>1/(b-a)$, then $n\mapsto a+1/(N+n)$ gives you an injection ${\bf N}\to (a,b)\cap {\bf Q}$.

Since you have an injection ${\bf Q}\to {\bf N}$, by Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder, you have a bijection $(a,b)\cap {\bf Q}\to {\bf Q}$ (by virtue of having injections both ways).

Answer (score 0):

First $A+|a|\subset \mathbb Q^+$ (the translated of $A$ by $|a|$) so you have $\#A\le\#\mathbb Q^+$ right away.

You need only an injection in the reverse way to conclude.

For $\mathbb R^+$ we usually proceed like this $\begin{cases}
f:[0,+\infty[\to[1,+\infty[ & f(x)=x+1\\
g:[1,+\infty[\to]0,1] & g(x)=1/x\\
h:]0,1]\to]a,b] & h(x)=a+x(b-a)\\
\end{cases}$

But since $a,b$ are rationnal too, these work also for $\mathbb Q^+$.

If we resume the bijection : $y=a+\frac{b-a}{x+1}\iff\frac 1{y-a}=\frac{x+1}{b-a}\iff x=\frac{b-a}{y-a}-1\iff x=\frac{b-y}{y-a}$

*Your bijection is slightly different, it is $x=\frac{b-y}{(y-a)(b-a)}$, but the division by $(b-a)$ changes nothing, $[0,+\infty[$ is not affected by an homothetic transform.*

You have also probably noticed that $A=]a,b[\cap\mathbb Q$ and not $]a,b]\cap\mathbb Q$, so you are not mapping the $0$ of $\mathbb Q^+$.

But it is not important for the conclusion, since $A$ is infinite, then $A\cup\{b\}$ and $A$ have the same cardinal.

If really you want to construct an explicit bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb Q^+$ you still need to transform $]a,b]$ to $]a,b[$ for instance by defining $U_n=\frac{(2^n-1)a+b}{2^n}$ and $\phi(U_n)=U_{n+1}$ and $\phi(q)=q$ elsewhere.

But exhibiting the explicit bijection is often not needed to show that two sets are equinumerous.